# Show location on Bing Maps (WinRT)

Tags: c#-4.0, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I want to display a location on bing maps in a WinRT app. But I only have only the name as information about the location. For example I want to show a map of 'New York'. Is it possible to display the map only with the information of a name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hitting the [Bing location API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx)?